# Windows disks query - check size

Tags: windows, automation, ansible, automated-tests, disk

I would like to check the disks size in windows servers with Ansible. If the size is less than what is defined in the specification we should see an alarm during the Ansible run.

`C:` and `D:` size can be a variable. Some servers have a `D:` drive but not all.

I have started to write this ansible task but I'm stuck at the condition.

```yaml
- name: Windows takeover checks
  hosts: '{{ servers }}'
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Get disk facts
      tags: disk
      community.windows.win_disk_facts:

    - name: get disk physical_disk and partition facts on the target
      win_disk_facts:
        filter:
          - physical_disk
          - partitions

    - name: Check disk C
      debug:
        msg: '{{ C }}'
      vars:
        C: '{{ ansible_facts.disks[0].size/1024|pow(3)|round|int }}'

    - name: Check disk D
      debug:
        msg: '{{ D }}'
      vars:
         D: '{{ ansible_facts.disks[1].size/1024|pow(3)|round|int }}'
      when: "{{ ansible_facts.disks[1].size }}" is not defined
```

Comment: 1) why are you running the disk fact module twice? 2) Don't stop typing when you say you are struck at writing a condition. You've shown your attempt. What doesn't work as expected? What do you expect instead? Read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section. 3) I don't see any attempt to compare the size to a predefined specified size in your example 4) Ansible is not a monitoring/alerting tool. Make sure you are not reinventing the wheel with the wrong tool.

Comment: Since you are new here (welcome by the way :)), please do not add needed precision to answer in comments: [edit] your question.